# Selecting layer in Road Graph plugin settings in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, shortest-path

I am currently using QGIS 2.10.1. and I am not able to select any layer when trying to configure the Road Graph plugin. What should I do?

Comment: When installed and enabled, you can select a layer if you go _Vector > Road graph > Settings_ from the toolbar. Then you should be able to set the line layer input and parameters from there :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself properly, but my point is that after I am entering in the Settings for Road Graph, I am not able to select any layer.

Answer (score 2):

The QGIS Road Graph Plugin can not use Polyline with Z-values. I solved this problem by removing Z-Values from my polyline shapefile. In QGIS: right mouse click on the layer /Save as... under Geometry choose Geometry type and uncheck Include z-dimension. [Here is also a solution with ArcGIS](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/68356#comment-309458).

Comment: By following the link in your answer it seems that this solution uses ArcGIS for Desktop but the asker makes no mention of using that product.

Answer (score 1):

right click the road layer and press save as. Then under geometry choose LineString and uncheck z-dimension. The z-dimension may have caused the problem. then try again.